# Unknown subcommand "mod" error while running go mod init

Tags: go, go-modules

I have installed the go language in my ubuntu using `sudo apt install golang-go`.

It was successfully installed. When i run `go version` I am getting `go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64`

but when i tried running `go mod init projectName` I am getting the following `error go: unknown subcommand "mod"`

Do I need to install mod package or am i missing something?  I have implemented the solution given by christophe in this [forum](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/go-unknown-subcommand-mod/15257) but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Preliminary module support was added in Go 1.11, so Go 1.10 knows no `mod` subcommand.

You need to install a newer, preferably the newest 1.14 version of Go. Get it from the [official downloads](https://golang.org/dl/) page. Go 1.10 is not even supported anymore (doesn't receive security patches).

The prepared packages of OSes usually lag behind new releases. I'd advise to always get Go from the official page.

Answer (score 1):

Because preliminary support for go-modules came in version 1.11 and 1.12.

[More here](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

I suggest that you install using the [linux build directly from golang](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.14.linux-amd64.tar.gz)